# Cannot connect to Redshift using dbVisulizer - SSL error (from Mac OS)

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, dbvisualizer

When I try to connect I get this error:

```
PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I downloaded the certificate from [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-ssl-support.html) and added it to KeyChain Access as you can see

[image]

I tried disabling ssl on the connection by setting ssl property to false, but that did not work.

So how can I connect using dbVisualizer?

Comment: you may need to check with your Redshift administrator to ensure that the certificate has been properly installed on the Redshift cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the location of the certificate file in the connection properties.

so at first locate the downloaded certificate file on your computer, then in `dbVisualizer`, open the connection properties for the `Redshift` connection you are trying to establish.

Now Under the `Advanced` tab, replace "" with the actual file path to the certificate file you downloaded

```
"sslrootcert="
```

and done.

Comment: Thanks. Same error. If I put the wrong filename, it throws an error saying cannot find file, so when I put the correct path and file, it doesn't throw that error, so I know it is finding the cert file. But I still get the same PKIX error. :(

Comment: @rmcsharry so  it could be that the certificate is not trusted by the JVM! you can try adding the certificate to the JVM truststore! plz let me know if you want more details.

Comment: do you mean the trustore on my local machine or on Amazon?